# OS X: setting display resolution and mirroring

Tags: mac-osx, mirror

How do I have a projector machine always mirror at 1024x768?  By default new users get 1920x1200 and non-mirrored.

Comment: @troggy, the question is tagged macosx.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two command line tools that will set mirroring and display resolution as you need.

**Mirror**

```
usage: mirror [option]  Passing more than one option produces undefined behavior.
  -h            Print this usage and exit.
  -t            Toggle mirroring (default behavior)
  -on           Turn Mirroring On
  -off          Turn Mirroring Off
  -q            Query the Mirroring state and print "on" or "off" to stdout
```

http://www.fabiancanas.com/Projects/MirrorDisplays

**SetGetRes**

```
Usage: ./getsetres [-l | 1..9 ] [ hor_res vert_res]

      -l  list resolution, depth and refresh rate of all displays
    1..9  display # (default: main display)
 hor_res  horizontal resolution
vert_res  vertical resolution
```

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090413120929454